# ExtJS -- submit selected checkbox values as string

Tags: extjs

I have a checkbox group component and each checkbox value upon form submit is passed as a separate parameter like so:

```
mycheckboxgroup: val1
mycheckboxgroup:val2
mycheckboxgroup:val3
```

How can I instead submit all checkbox group values in a comma separated string?

```
mycheckboxgroup: val1, val2, val3
```

I tried using the `getSubmitData` method but that did not work. The values are still submitted in separate params.

Here is a snippet of my CheckBoxGroup class:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.form.field.CheckboxGroup",{
   extend:"Ext.form.CheckboxGroup",

   vertical:true,
   columns:2,
   getSubmitData:function(){ 
      var fldNm = this.name; 
      return this.getValue()[fldNm].toString();
   },

  initComponent:function(){ 
     .....
     .....

     this.callParent(arguments);
  }

});
```

I am using Ext 6.0.2

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your form, upon submission, will query the checkboxes, not the group as a whole.

You can, however, create a custom component with non-persistent checkboxes and a hidden field that aggregates the value. It may need some fine tuning, but something like this:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.ux.CheckboxGroup",{
    extend:"Ext.form.CheckboxGroup",
    xtype:'mycheckboxgroup',
    initComponent:function() {
        var me = this,
            hf = Ext.widget({xtype:'hiddenfield',name:me.name});
        me.callParent(arguments);
        var checkboxes = me.query('checkbox'),
            onChange = function(cb, nv) {
                var arr = [];
                Ext.each(checkboxes,function(item) {
                    if(item.checked) arr.push(item.inputValue);
                });
                hf.setValue(arr.join(', '));
            };
        Ext.each(checkboxes, function(item) {
            console.log(item);
            item.on('change',onChange);
            item.submitValue = false; // do not submit the checkbox value
        })
        me.add(hf);
    }
});
```

Relevant fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1mim